# Excluding Null Values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

In my syntax why does the `NOT IN` statement not exclude `NULL` values?  To me, if `NULL` does not exist in `#GoodAnswers` it should return the `dv`

Below is syntax, can someone help explain this to me?

```
Create Table #GoodAnswer
(
  answer1 varchar(100)
  ,dv varchar(10)
)

Insert Into #GoodAnswer Values 
('Blue','Yes'), 
('Pink','No'),
('Purple','No')

Create Table #Data
(
  bbc varchar(100)
  ,answer varchar(100)
)

Insert Into #Data Values ('lal', NULL), ('raj', 'Orange'), ('enif', 'Zoo')

Select bbc
    , case 
        when answer not in (
            Select answer1 
            from #GoodAnswer
        ) then (
            Select answer1
            from #GoodAnswer 
            where dv = 'Yes'
        ) 
        else answer 
        end as [Valid Answer]
FROM #Data

Drop table #GoodAnswer
Drop Table #Data
```

My data returned from this result-set is

```
+------+--------------+
| BBC  | VALID ANSWER |
+------+--------------+
| lal  | NULL         |
| raj  | Blue         |
| enif | Blue         |
+------+--------------+
```

I feel that instead of `NULL` being returned it should return `Blue` since that is the `dv` in the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` is special. [It is neither equal nor non-equal.](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones/2010/10/13/common-sql-server-mistakes-_1320_-equals-null/)

Given the same temp tables in your example, consider the results from these queries:

```
--returns 3 rows
SELECT * FROM #Data;

--returns 2 rows
SELECT * FROM #Data
WHERE answer NOT IN (SELECT answer1 FROM #GoodAnswer);

--returns 0 rows
SELECT * FROM #Data
WHERE answer IN (SELECT answer1 FROM #GoodAnswer);
```

This is because the definition of  `NULL` is that it is **unknown**. Since you don't know the value of it, you can't evaluate it's equality or inequality. Instead, you have to explicitly query for `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the `NULL` from the `else` clause of your Case structure because NULL doesn't evaluate.
NULL bypasses the `when answer not in` test.

Null values can be difficult to navigate. Most recently I've seen [this article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/03/the-joy-of-joining-on-nulls/) from Brent Ozar's team discussing NULL values and their effect on join logic and performance.

For most evaluations you can use ISNULL but keep in mind that may affect query performance.